# Performance Test on Viber Chat Bot

Tags: performance, jmeter, viber-bot

I want to do the performance test for the viber bot but I cannot access through web so cannot be think about performance test on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Viber has [REST API](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/) so you could use JMeter to invoke this API methods in order to i.e. [send messages](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#send-message) to your bot and check the responses.

You will need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) configured to send [`X-Viber-Auth-Token`](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#authentication-token) and that would be it

Comment: But only we put Hi using the bot can we capture it http recorder like WhatsApp web

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing web version of Viber so there is nothing you can record using your browser. You can [record Viber Desktop network traffic](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) and then replay it, however I'm not sure that this is something you're looking for.